# Implementation of communication protocol between embedded system based on ARM cpu and JAVA application which simulate elevator.

Tags: java, c++, arm, crc

I need to create a communication module, which will communicate via serial interface with the simulator elevator. The communication protocol is asynchronous and uses CRC8 to verify the correct transmission.
Elevator simulator emulates a asynchronous bus type multi-master. Each device have own address. Each device can asynchronously access a bus as master.

[Packet requirement:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wTdp.png)

a board which should control a elevator is FRDM KL25Z based on AMR core.
CRC8 is calculated from transmitter address, receiver address and from data.
For serial communication I uses the standard Serial Interface, specifying the internal (USBTX, USBRX) pins to connect to the Serial Port routed over USB.

Where should I start, with implement this requirement?
How should i implement a CRC8?
Thank you for tips and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You said it yourself; the Embedded system is communicating on a serial interface. To start, get a Serial library for your system and Java, then try to get some basic messages sent between the two. CRC8 is just a verification / checksum algorithm. Don't worry about that until you have some basic communication. First send bits, then worry about constructing your desired packets, then work on the protocol between the two.

Comment: Java app is already maked, not by me. It look like this:
[link](http://imgur.com/a/TsXn3)

Comment: You'll need to find either the definition of the CRC-8 from documentation on the system, or sniff several packets and reverse-engineer the CRC-8 parameters. There are many different CRC-8 definitions, so you first have to find out which one it is.